# Spring Data Cassandra can't instantiate Reconnection Policy from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I configured my spring data cassandra client using spring boot **application.yml** and autoconfiguration.

It works for me but only when I not use spring.data.reconnection-policy property. 
When I use any of them (**com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy** or **com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ExponentialReconnectionPolicy**) I goet this error on startup:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy]: **No default constructor found**; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy.()
>       at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.lambda$as$2(PropertyMapper.java:207) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.to(PropertyMapper.java:302) ~[spring-boot-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration.cassandraCluster(CassandraAutoConfiguration.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2f475e40.CGLIB$cassandraCluster$0() ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.3.RELEASE.jar:2.0.3.RELEASE]

I extended policy class and added default constructor there. With new class inside my application.yml everything works. Is it possible to configure reconnection policy without workaround or this is a bug?

Thanks in advance.

This is my application.yml:

spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      # Name of the Cassandra cluster.
      cluster-name: "Test Cluster"

```
  # Cluster node addresses.
  contact-points: 10.247.198.137

  # Login user of the server.
  username: cassandra

  # Login password of the server.
  password: cassandra

  # Compression supported by the Cassandra binary protocol.
  compression: none

 # Port of the Cassandra server.
  port: 9042

  # Socket option: connection time out.
  connect-timeout: 5000ms

  # Queries consistency level.
  consistency-level: three

  # Queries default fetch size.
  fetch-size: 5000

  # Keyspace name to use.
  keyspace-name: testkeyspace

  # Enable SSL support.
  ssl: true

  # Class name of the load balancing policy.
  load-balancing-policy: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.RoundRobinPolicy

  # Reconnection policy class.
  reconnection-policy: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.ConstantReconnectionPolicy


  # Class name of the retry policy.
  retry-policy: com.datastax.driver.core.policies.DefaultRetryPolicy

  # Heartbeat interval after which a message is sent on an idle connection to make sure it's still alive. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
  pool.heartbeat-interval: 30s

  # Idle timeout before an idle connection is removed. If a duration suffix is not specified, seconds will be used.
  pool.idle-timeout: 120s

  # Maximum number of requests that get queued if no connection is available.
  pool.max-queue-size: 256

  # Pool timeout when trying to acquire a connection from a host's pool.
  pool.pool-timeout: 5000ms

  # Socket option: read time out.
  read-timeout: 5000ms

  # Type of Cassandra repositories to enable.
  repositories.type: auto

  # Queries serial consistency level.
  serial-consistency-level: three

  # Schema action to take at startup.
  schema-action: RECREATE_DROP_UNUSED
```

Comment: Looks like an issue in Spring Boot's autoconfiguration for Apache Cassandra. Care to file a bug report at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/14461